# Functional style with conditional returns in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, lisp

Suppose we have a function with the following structure:

```
def f():
    # ...
    # some computations
    # ...
    if something_is_wrong_with_previous_computations:
        return None
    # ...
    # some other computations
    # ...
    if something_is_wrong_with_previous_computations2:
        return some_variable
    #...
    return result
```

As I see it, using `return` statement in the middle of a function is not functional at all. If we were in some lispy language we would have the `let` (then computations could be written with `let*`) statement, which would help us deal with these situations with ease. Unfortunately, we don't have it here. What should we do?

- Simulate `let` with creating lots of nested functions and calling them in place?
- Use something like `Maybe` monad or another complex stuff like that?
- Don't waste our time and write it imperatively?
- Something else?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would do this in LISP (any dialect)? I'm curious because I don't see how let can help in this situation and want to know.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych "For great justice" ©. Joking aside, it's more for the sake of learning, then for production

Comment: @jbmeerkat ok, I agree, it's not about `let`, but `let*` (scheme): 
```
(define (f)
  (let* ([v1 #| some-computation |#]
         [v2 #| some-computation-2 |#]
         #|etc|#)
    (if wrong1
        Null
        (let* (#|some-more-computations|#)
          (if wrong2
              some-var
              (let* ...))))))
``` (I hope you can read that)))

Comment: As I can understand, example in Scheme is pretty similar to the code you wrote in your question in Python except returns. I think the key difference here is that in Scheme "returns" are implicit, but in Python they are strictly explicit. You can do it in Python with single return but if will be more like C-style, not functional https://pastebin.com/xgGD0iBn

Comment: @jbmeerkat your words make sense. However, your particular example is not quite applicable in my case, since `some_other_computation` cannot be done on `wrong(result1)`. Though I feel like your answer made me think in a more correct way. Anyway, you can make an answer here, but we'll wait a bit until someone else answers too (or maybe not)

Comment: The difference is that Lisps are expression languages: Python isn't.  My opinion is that if you try to write programs in non-expression-languages as if they were expression languages that ... it's easier to just use an expression language rather than to try and twist the other language into one.

Comment: @tfb, if only I had such an opportunity) One good and notable alternative is [hylang](https://github.com/hylang/hy). Unfortunately this (really cool!) language lacks /drumroll.../ `let` forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `return` statement *anywhere* in a function is not functional.

In Python, you have no choice.

The Lisp code

```
(defun sgnum (x)
  (cond
    ((< x 0) -1)
    ((zerop x) 0)
   (t 1)))
```

turns into Python as

```py
def sgnum(x):
  if x < 0:
    return -1
  elif x == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return 1
```

In Lisp, we know we have deviated from functional coding when we use variable assignment, or the "program feature": an explicit `progn` construct, or an implicit equivalent, or any of is cousins like `prog` or `prog1`. A functional function in Lisp always has a body which is made up of a single expression (or possibly no expressions at all).

You can redefine what you mean by "functional coding" in Python. How about these
rules:

1. Every statement in a "functional function" must be a single statement; it cannot be followed by another statement. Thus, the whole body of a function is a single statement, and in it are embedded single statements.
2. No statement in the function may allow control to fall through it. Every statement must return. Thus `return` is not only considered "functional" but essential to achieving this goal.
3. A variable may be defined, but not redefined. Parallel, mutually exclusive control flows may assign the same variable different values, but no variable can be assigned more than once in the same control flow.

With these kinds of rules, you can get the program to **have a control flow graph resembling that a program in the pure Lisp style**: a control graph that is basically a tree of decisions with embedded calculations and variable binding, at the leaves of which are values to be returned.

Speaking of variable binding, we should probably have a fourth rule:

4. A statement may be preceded by a sequence of fresh variable assignments that contain no side effects. Such a sequence, together with the statement which follows it, counts as one statement.

Arguably also a fifth one:

5. No statement must be used which evaluates any contained expression or statement more than once.

Otherwise we permit loops, which are not functional. This is tricky because some looping constructs are relatively well behaved, like implicitly stepping a dummy variable over the elements of a list.  The only way you can tell it's not functional is that a lexical closure captured in the loop will easily reveal there is only one variable being mutated and not a fresh variable being bound for each iteration.

According to these rules, `sgnum` is "functional": it contains just one `if/elif/else` statement, which does not allow control to fall through it: every branch returns:

This version of `sgnum` is not "functional" any more:

```py
def sgnum(x):
  if x < 0:
    return -1
  if x == 0:
    return 0
  return 1
```

It contains three statements in sequence. Whereas the following is "functional" even though it also consists of three statements:

```py
def distance(x0, y0, x1, y1):
  xd = x1 - x0
  yd = y1 - y0
  return math.sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd)
```

These meet the rules. The first two statements bind fresh variables, meeting rule 3, so are permitted by 4 to precede a statement. The return statement meets rules 1 and 2. This is very similar to:

```
(defun distance (x0 y0 x1 y1)
  (let ((xd (- x1 x0))
        (yd (- y1 y0)))
    (sqrt (+ (* xd xd) (* yd yd)))))
```

Lastly, note how our rules are at odds with the ancient programming advice of "have only one exit point in a function". That little tidbit you may find in some coding conventions is quite anti-functional. To achieve a single point of return in a nontrivial function requires imperative style control flows through multiple statements and/or variable assignments. From the functional point of view, it is a myopic, silly rule; but it makes sense in those contexts where it is recommended, because it can help improve very poorly structured imperative code.

Comment: Your conventions seem quite reasonable. By returning from `if`'s we're really emulating `if` from Lisp. Though I would argue on the fifth rule. We can generalize that in the following statement: we MUST permit loops in Python, otherwise any nontrivial logic cannot be expressed in this language. Maps and reduces are good, but sometimes they are totally not enough (like any higher-order function). At least I can't see how to use them without making a huge mess. In a functional language we'd have tail recursion for cases like that. But we don't.